# PHP: Call to undefined function gmp_add

Tags: php, macos, symfony

I am trying to use the `gmp_add` method but it is throwing an error:

[2018-01-26 20:58:56] local.ERROR: Call to undefined function gmp_add() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined function gmp_add() at /var/www/app/Clients/iota-php-port/kerl-php/conv.php:110)

So I installed gmp with `brew install homebrew/php/php70-gmp` and confirmed that it is installed:

[image]

But it is still throwing the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: `--without-gmp`?

Comment: how do i update it with gmp? i noticed that too but i don't know how to restart it